# Different Royalty's % based on listing price of nft

Tags: nft

I am just practising with Solana and I would like to know how to set different royalty % based on if a user lists below floor price.

I know degods have done this so if anyone knows how I can do this please help point me in the right directions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to programatically change the royalty by updating the metadata of the NFT if you hold the Update Authority. You can use [metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/update.htmlhttps://metaboss.rs/update.html) or you can check this script i have written long time back to update NFT [here](https://github.com/0xPratik/update-metadata)